# Допустимо ли двоеточие?

Tags: двоеточие

### Тем самым автор хотел показать: любить можно за всё.

Можно ли объяснить двоеточие в данном предложении заменой на союз "что"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. В этом случае первая часть предупреждает о том, что изложение продолжится и далее. В таких предложениях в первой части употребляется, как правило, один из глаголов: сказать, подумать, видеть, знать, слышать, чувствовать и т. п. Например: «Петр и Анна знали: у них обязательно будет большая и шумная семья». Между частями этого предложения и подобных ему можно поставить союз что, превратив его в сложноподчиненное предложение.

*Тем самым автор хотел показать: любить можно за всё.*- *Тем самым автор хотел показать,что любить можно за всё.*

Хотел показать = хотел сказать (глагол речи).